# Large Multi search, to match numbers in one column, with Hyperlinks containing those numbers in another column

Tags: excel, search, matching

I have one column with about 4000 Part Numbers. Another column with about 8000 hyperlink URLs containing the part numbers. I want to match the part numbers with thier URLs. Manually searching each one will take forever.

Answer (score 1):

Let your Part number be in `A1` and your URLs in column `F`, than use in `B1`

```
=INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1,1/ISNUMBER(FIND(A1,F:F)),0))
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it. Drag this formula down.

Note, this formula finds first URL, which contains path number.